# Spark DataGrid selected cell edit on keyDown

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am using spark DataGrid. I want to emulate Excel Behaviour = When single cell is selected and users start to type on keyboard the selected cells goes to editing mode. I did it by starting gridItemEditorSession on 1st keyDown event but the problem I have is that after starting gridItemEditorSession value in the cell is selected so 2nd keyDown removes 1st keyDown character ;/

Here is demo:
Simply select any cell and start typying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onKeyDown():void
            {
                trace(dataGrid.grid.anchorRowIndex)
                trace(dataGrid.grid.caretRowIndex)

                dataGrid.startItemEditorSession(dataGrid.grid.anchorRowIndex, dataGrid.grid.anchorColumnIndex)
            }

            private function onGridRollOver():void
            {

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" requestedRowCount="5" width="350" editable="true"
        height="300" selectionMode="multipleCells" keyDown="onKeyDown()"
        gridRollOver="onGridRollOver()">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:DataItem key="1000" name="Abrasive" price="100.11" call="false"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1001" name="Brush" price="110.01" call="true"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1002" name="Clamp" price="120.02" call="false"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1003" name="Drill" price="130.03" call="true"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1004" name="Epoxy" price="140.04" call="false"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1005" name="File" price="150.05" call="true"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1006" name="Gouge" price="160.06" call="false"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1007" name="Hook" price="170.07" call="true"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1008" name="Ink" price="180.08" call="false"/>
                <s:DataItem key="1009" name="Jack" price="190.09" call="true"/>             
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I see I can edit the value in the cell as expected. Would you please your problem with more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familair with Flex, but it sounds like you have a string handling issue. Something like

```
private function handleKeydown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    output_txt.text = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
}
```

instead of

```
private function handleKeydown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    output_txt.appendText(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
}
```

Make sure you're appending input to your text instead of replacing.

Comment: This is internal DataGrid implementation, so I do not have access to textField instance ;/ SO the real question is hotw to bypass this 'internal' behaviour in spark DataGrid.

Comment: Find a method in the api that will let you append text, send it in all at once by creating a faux textfield above the cell and sending it over on key 13, or rewrite the internals :P